# I'm doing a hash verification project, and after I store the hash, and want to verify it, it returns false after I check it against the new hash

Tags: python, hash

I create a hash, and store it in a .txt file (will encrypt it later), but when I create a new hash and check against the stored one, It returns false even though the hashes are the exact same. Help?
Relevant code: `

```
    def testHash(expectedHash, testHash):
        try:
            if expectedHash == testHash:
                return True
            else: 
                return False
        except Exception as err:
            print("Error, unkonwn if valid hash.")
            print(f"Error: {err}")
            return False
```

`
Here's  the code to store the hash:

```
  def storeHash(hash):
   stored_hashes = open("storedHashes.txt", "a")
   stored_hashes.write(hash+"\n")
   stored_hashes.close()
```

And here's the code to get the stored hash:

```
def getHash(index):
    stored_hashes = open("storedHashes.txt", "r+")
    read_hash = stored_hashes.readlines(index)
    clean_read_hash = ' '.join(read_hash) #required to remove the [] and \n
    return clean_read_hash
```

Note: it returns no errors, but does not return True either.
Complete code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/2XpbmXaP
password: hashVerify

- I know the file exertion on line 18 is .hs, that was a side track that led noewere, it should be .txt
- Fun little fact, Windows and other  OS's allow any file extension, and just use the things after the . if they don't know what it is as the type.
- Note: the content of the testFile is "test for hashes"

Comment: I know I should add a signature and salt, and Ill do that later after I get this figured out.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check: https://pastebin.com/2XpbmXaP for the complete code!

Comment: Password: hashVerify

Comment: `.readlines(index)` makes no sense - the parameter to that method is almost never used, and has absolutely nothing to do with selecting a particular line from the file, as you seem to expect.  And you still need to remove the newline from the file data - the line you've commented does no such thing.

Comment: @jasonharper, thx, I'm new to python file management. That really helps!

Comment: `hash` is a built-in Python function and your "storeHash" function is trying to use it as a variable name.

Comment: I used .readlines instead of readline as it gave something, not just 4. (yes, if you use readline, it returns 4 for some reason)

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I wondered why VS code was making that yellow... it seamed to work fine though

Comment: I just noticed something it is hashing the path, not the file content! I'm now going to have to do more file management... shouldn't be too hard, just have to add. read()

Comment: It appears that when you're writing the hash to the file, Python is being helpful and calling `str` on that hash object for you.  But when you're reading the file you get a string, and the string is **never** going to be equal to the original hash object.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for certain since you only define the functions and don't show the logic of calling them. But it looks like you just need to fix your call to `stored_hashes.readlines`. Change `stored_hashes.readlines(index)` to `stored_hashes.readlines()[index]`; as mentioned in a comment, the parameter accepted by `stored_hashes.readlines` (which returns a list, by the way) is not the index of the list but rather the total number of characters to allow to be read. That means, with your current code, you are always comparing the "test hash" to a list of every hash in your text file.